# Get value from span class

Tags: javascript, html

I want get value from `span`, like in example below

```
<span class="price bid down_trend">6259.00</span>
```

but the class changes from `price bid down_trend` to `price bid up_trend` and there is my question:

**How get value from the span when the class was changing ?**

I think about something like that:

```
var bidValue = document.getElementByClassName('price bid');
```

But did it be able to find the value of `span` ?

Comment: If you need a single element in your code such as the one here, you should mark it with an id and use `getElementById()` or access directly with it's id, to avoid collecting tons of unrelated elements and filtering them for the one you need.

Comment: But I get info from other site so I can not change sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't give space in the classname:

```
var bidValue = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML;
```

or use `querySelector`:

```
var bidValue = document.querySelector('.price.bid').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Hmm You are right, because the span contained many classes. Second option that You wrote looks good I will try it :)

Comment: But how about classes after `price.bid` ? There can be `down_trend` or `up_trend`. Can You tell more about using dot `.` ? It shouldn't looks like `document.querySelector('.price.bid.'); ? With dot after `bid` ?

Comment: @Czarq92 dot after bid is not required. Dot `.` is a class selector followed by classname. It will check for elements which has these two classes `price` and `bid`. Whether they have any other class or not, won't matter. Look at this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Comment: I try `document.querySelector('.price.bid')` and it return many elements, how get only once ?

Comment: @Czarq92 `querySelector` returns only one element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector Can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

In case that you want to use jquery

```
$('.price.bid').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this issue is as follows.

```js
var dateVal = document.querySelectorAll('.date-active span')[0].innerHTML
console.log("date value is ", dateVal)
```

```html
<div class="date-active">
  <span>11</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            alert("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
        });
    });
    </script>
<p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```

Hope it helps;)